# What type of "it" is used in "It had been agreed…"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, it-its-itself

What type of "it" is used in this sentence:

> It had been agreed that they should all meet in the big barn as soon as Mr. Jones was safely out of the way.

Comment: As the sentence can be reformulated (rather inelegantly) into << That they should all meet in the big barn as soon as Mr. Jones was safely out of the way had been agreed. >>, it is an it-cleft (cleft sentence). As [Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/it-cleft-sentence-term-1691086) states: << An it-cleft begins with nonreferential it (the "cleft pronoun") >>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to distinguish it-cleft and extraposition? 'It was Ben that found it' v 'It was clear that Ben found it'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/597679/how-to-distinguish-it-cleft-and-extraposition-it-was-ben-that-found-it-v-it) Or  [... It's my children who want me to ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175549/these-are-my-children-who-want-me-to-or-its-my-children-who-want-me-to/175554#175554)? 'dummy _it_')