# How to properly use is vs it's

Tags: word-usage

I have a situation trying to figure it out the correct usage of `it` vs `it's`. I've watched [a tutorial](http://www.engvid.com/is-or-its/) about this subject but not so sure how to apply the last example in my phrase.

*... She is a lovely girl. Born an artist, `is` an individual driven by emotions.* OR *... She is a lovely girl.Born an artist, `it's` an individual driven by emotions.*

in order to be clear for me, we also have the `he` version:

*... He is a good guy. Born an artist, `is` an individual driven by emotions.* OR *... He is a good guy.Born an artist, `it's` an individual driven by emotions.*

I am confused because in my case, I have comma but no conjunction words like but, end, etc.
Thank you,

Comment: I think you probably mean "Born an artist, he's an individual driven by emotions." (or she's).

Comment: True but I have already used `she` in previous sentence, this is a phrase. `she is a lovely girl` for example. After that will come `Born an artist ... an individual driven by emotions`.

Comment: The statement "Born an artist, is an individual..." lacks a subject and is ungrammatical; "an individual" is the subject complement. It's a grammatical **question,** where inversion makes "an individual" the subject.

Comment: Even if we have the subject in the previous sentence is still ungrammatical?

Comment: You would never use `it's` for a live human.  (And there's nothing wrong with using `she` twice.)

Comment: A question for ELĹ.

Comment: @HotLicks But you can use *it* [for an infant!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159009/is-is-it-a-girl-or-a-boy-really-calling-the-infant-an-it/159041#159041) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Born an artist, **is** an individual driven by emotions.
> 2. Born an artist, **it's** an individual driven by emotions.

In English the verb in the main clause in any sentence must have a Subject (outside of imperative sentences). In actual fact every tensed verb in English must have a subject. This subject cannot be inferred from an earlier clause.

Sentence (1) is ungrammatical because the tensed verb in the main clause, *is*, has no subject. Sentence (2) is incorrect because the subject of the sentence is a woman or man (depending on whether it corresponds to the Original Poster's first or second set of examples). We don't generally use "*it*" for adult people in English: we need to use a feminine or masculine pronoun as appropriate. Either of the following is therefore acceptable:

- Born an artist, **she's** an individual driven by emotions.
- Born an artist, **he's** an individual driven by emotions.

Notice that the verb *born* in the subordinate clause here does not need a subject because it's not tensed and isn't the main verb in the clause.

Answer (score 0):

As an earlier commenter said, neither of the following is grammatical unless you mean to pose a question, in which case you need a question mark. So, these would not be grammatical:

> She is a lovely girl. Born an artist, is an individual driven by emotions.

OR

> She is a lovely girl.Born an artist, it's an individual driven by emotions.

This would be grammatical, but doesn't seem to be what you're trying to say:

> She is a lovely girl. Born an artist, is an individual driven by emotions?

Assuming that this you are making a statement, would this work for you?

> She is a lovely girl. Born an artist, *she* is an individual driven by emotions.

The male equivalent would then be...

> He is a good guy. Born an artist, *he* is an individual driven by emotions.

Comment: As long as it's not a problem in using _he_ or _she_ twice, I'l use your last and/or @chasly from UK solution. Thank you both.